# Public class and Global Variables

Tags: android, class, global

How can you access variables content in

```
    public class Global extends Application {
    String gotUsername;
    String gotPassword;
    String gotIPAddress;

    void onStartCommand(Intent intent){
        Bundle gotAuthen = intent.getExtras();
        gotUsername = gotAuthen.getString("key1");
        gotPassword = gotAuthen.getString("key2");
        gotIPAddress = gotAuthen.getString("key3"); 
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

from a Public class like this one?

```
Public Class MyApp {

}
```

I tried with

```
Global Username = (Global) getApplicationContext();
```

but I found out `getApplicationContext();` is used for Activities only.

How should I do it then?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the variables in the `Global` class static.

```
static String variable;
```

then you can access them by doing `String stuff = Global.variable;`

Comment: Don't make a new Instance of the `Application` object, Applications, Activities, Services are not meant to be directly instantiated.

Comment: @A--C Oh yeah, didn't think about what he was extending. I'll fix it.

Comment: Amazingggg! Thanks! I've been looking for a solution the whole day! I understand that it might not be the proper way to do it, but my time is counted and I'm learning this step by step. Thanks again!!